# What to call the activity of providing workshops and training

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

I have organized and conducted technology workshops and trainings for my employer and several clients. In some cases, it was rather teacher-oriented and lecture-like, while in others it was rather a collaborative meeting where I was more of a facilitator.

How could the title of a list of such workshops and trainings in a self-description look like?

"Offered workshops/trainings" - sounds too ambiguous, as in "I offered them, but nobody wanted one".

"Facilitated workshops/trainings"- correct in some cases, but suggests too little involvement overall.

"Executed", "conducted", "held", "performed" - perhaps, I don't have enough linguistic intuition to decide, but "executed" and "performed" don't feel right.

Comment: What's wrong with ***provide***, which you use in your title? Or ***organized*** and ***conducted*** from the text.

Comment: To me, "provide" sounds too vague, "organize" - too ambiguous - could also be said about the assistant who booked the room and sent out invitations. "conducted" sounds ok, but I just could not decide clearly. As a non-native english speaker in a non-english speaking country, I cannot be very sure of my own intuition. Languages tend to encroach on each other's territory :)

Comment: You *led* technology workshops and trained employees.

Comment: If I said *"I provide training workshops in Linux"*, I think it would be perverse for anyone to assume I might just deal with the administrative tasks involved (that would be *"I **help** provide training"*).

Comment: Hmm 'led' didn't occur to me, I like it. And 'provide' sounds better to me than 'conduct'. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: What about; **'Tailored Workshops & Training.'** suggesting that your workshops and training can be adapted as needed.  There's no plural of training by the way.

Comment: @TRomano Please phrase your answer in the form of an answer.

Comment: @TRomano, Would you please answer this question with your excellent suggestion so we can upvote it? Alex Trebek and I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *led* technology workshops and trained employees.